# Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim with Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Using the firebase python API, I created custom tokens for user Ids for my application, this is to enable verification and possibly request for user data from the backend.

Here is my sample code:

```
   #create custom token with uid
    custom_token = firebase_admin.auth.create_custom_token(uid)
    print custom_token
    decoded_token = 
    firebase_admin.auth.verify_id_token(id_token=custom_token, 
   check_revoked=True)
```

However I get the following error on firebase with Python:

```
Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "sec-vef-sandbox" but got "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve ID token.
```

I've made sure the projectId matches 'sec-vef-sandbox', so don't see where the error comes from. After checking other posts on Stack Overflow it appears it's a firebase bug. I wonder if there's a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase admin sdk verifies only ID tokens and custom tokens do not fall under this category. So there's no workaround with this and only to check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) on how to get valid ID tokens from the client. Also this thread on [GitHub](http://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/51) will shed more light on this issue specific to the [firebase-python-admin](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python) SDK.